# Limit the number of opportunities made in a certain account

Tags: apex, trigger

How can I limit the number of opportunities that can be made for an account? As much as possible, I don't want to use triggers. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Typically it is difficult to validate between two records without the use of Apex. But in this instance there is an option.

Account has the ability to do a roll-up summary field what counts the number of child opportunity records.

You could do exactly what you are asking by

1. Add a roll-up summary field that counts how many opportunities are a child of an account. We'll call it `opportunity_count__c`
2. Add a validation rule to Account that checks for `opportunity_count__c` to be greater than or equal to your threshold value

Comment: Does that mean that if my opportunity_count__c is greater than the value I set, i can no longer create an opportunity in that account?

Comment: yes. isn't that what you want?

Comment: but i cant see opportunity count in account when i create a validation rule

Comment: you created the roll-up summary?

Comment: yeah.. no validation rule upon creating it

Comment: also in validation rule creation no opportunity_count__c. i am in the accounts object

Comment: hard to say what's wrong. I have just built this myself exactly as I said and it works a treat. I'll try to make my explanation more clear.